# How start activity from background in Android 9 Pie?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, background, android-9.0-pie

How is it possible to start an activity in the background on Android Pie
version?

I didn't have a problem with previous versions.

Comment: Please go through this documentation for more details - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: @Vijay , I see that docs, i have last state : The app has been granted the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission by the user.  But also I can't start my activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was from MIUI in xiaomi, **MIUI prevent from displaying pop up window that comes from backgroud**. I get it's permissions and then problem solved.